# What do I call it when my wife regularly attends to her own wants and desires, seldom considering me?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

My wife regularly attends to her own wants and desires seldom considering me.

As an example, she will buy special snacks for her knowing I enjoy them also but neither buy anything for me nor offer me any. If I ask for some she  will either become irritated or make a big deal of it using body language to tell of her displeasure. Another example is we both smoke. We don’t make a lot of money so we usually run out of cigarettes and share a pack. When I buy them I always give her half, 10 cigarettes. When she buys them, first she usually doesn't tell me. When I see her smoking and ask for some she gives me 5 or 6. If I go take some on my own she says I am stealing them because I didn't ask. If she opens them at home and decides to give me some, again she keeps the majority for herself. She also often will buy for herself and not tell me.

Today I experimented, buying myself a pack and not telling her. She came to me and asked if I had any cigarettes. When she realized I had purchased a pack and had given her none, she got an attitude immediately. “You bought cigarettes and didn't tell me? So, you're hoarding, huh? Bad karma.”

What is this? It happens too often concerning too many things for me not to be concerned.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure that *etymology** is the right tag until you actually have a phrase whose origin  you can investigate. Maybe just *phrase* or *single word* would be more suitable.

Comment: A phrase that comes to mind is, "one law for the rich and another for the poor"  That's similar but not quite right. I think we need an actual sample sentence from you that uses the word/phrase in context. You can leave a blank space where the required term should go. That extra context makes it much easier for us.

Comment: I'd call it "monarchy".

Comment: Hi @Ken Pepper and welcome to ELU. You've expressed your situation very clearly and I hope you get an answer that may help you consider ways of resolving this difficult problem with your wife. Sometimes, it's useful to have an impartial third-party present, eg a counsellor or pastor, to assist in discussions between you and your wife. Best wishes:)

Comment: Look up *hypocrite* and its synonyms.

Comment: I'm afraid you better ask your wife outright what is the matter.

Comment: This is a personal problem, not an English problem. People come here all the time looking for labels they can use against others whose behavior they disapprove of. [We should not help them.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4842/can-anything-be-done-about-mean-spirited-requests-for-terminology)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it looks like you're in an unhealthy relationship. You should ask help from a good marriage councillor. Knowing a word, phrase or idiom that describes your wife's antagonistic behaviour might help you verbalise the situation, but it will do little in the way of improving your life.

Comment: @tchrist I don't think the OP is actually looking for an insult, he just wants to be able to put a "label" on his wife's behaviour. I think, rather than a mean-spirited request, it is asking whether the pattern of behaviour has a name.

Comment: You might consider this to be "self-centered" behavior.  (And the most effective way to solve the cigarette problem is to stop smoking.)

Comment: this is a website for discussion of the english language, not for the dispensation of relationship advice . . . ugh.  (thank you, @tchrist -- just noticed you've already made this point.)

Comment: Try asking your question at [**Cognitive Sciences**](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), I would hope that your question be taken more seriously there. Give it a go. I have seen questions less articulate and far more vague than yours being upvoted mindlessly. Your question certainly did not deserve three downvotes.

Comment: The simple word for this is ***selfish***

Comment: @Jim - Exactly.  And the noun is **selfishness**.  By the way, a person can have lots of good qualities but still be a bit selfish.  Also, this sounds like a great way to quit smoking!  Anyway, now you have the word to use when you sit down and have your chat with her.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you shaped your question tells me that it is "**[hypocrisy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrisy)**" (especially if your wife doesn't behave like that with other people) or just the trivial "**[double standard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20standard)**". Hope that gets you started

Answer (score -1):

Double dealer,double standard,two faced, hypocrete or similar other words can mean the situation of the poster.

It goes to mean, two set of rules one professed, the other practised.
A double standard comes to mean the different set of principles for similar situation.
However, my preferences are the words with 'double' or 'two'.

•• Jack sees the double standard at work in her behaviour, and he is pretty annoyed.